# AJAX data not passing to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having trouble passing AJAX data to PHP. I am experienced with PHP but new to JavaScript.

**HTML / JavaScript**

```
<input type="text" id="commodity_code"><button id="button"> = </button>

<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$('#button').click(function()
{
  var commodity_code = $('#commodity_code').val();

  $.ajax({                                      
  url: 'get_code.php',  
  data: "commodity_code: commodity_code",
  dataType: 'json',
  success:function(data) {
        var commodity_desc = data[0];
        alert(commodity_desc);
    }  
  });
}); 

</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$commodity_code = $_POST['commodity_code'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM oc_commodity_codes WHERE code = '$commodity_code'");
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo json_encode($array);
```

I know the general AJAX fetch and PHP code is working as I can manually create the $commodity_code variable and the script works fine. I think my issue lies somewhere in passing the AJAX data to my PHP script.

Comment: the `mysql_` database library that you're using is end-of-life. It was deprecated several years ago and removed entirely in PHP 7 due to security concerns, including (but not limited to) its inability to support parameterised queries to better protect against SQL Injection attacks. As it is, you are running unsupported code and your system is very vulnerable to injection attacks. If this is new code, you should absolutely **not** be using `mysql_`, if it's old code you should plan to upgrade a.s.a.p. You should switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO` and start using parameterised prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you, this is old code and will be changed to mysqli

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add the `method: 'POST'` in your AJAX Call. And you have some issues with your call. Check below:

```
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'get_code.php',
  method: "POST",                         // Change here.
  data: {commodity_code: commodity_code}, // Change here.
  dataType: 'json',                       
  success:function(data) {
        var commodity_desc = data[0];
        alert(commodity_desc);
  }  
});
```

Or to make it simple, use the shorthand function:

```
$.post('get_code.php', {commodity_code: commodity_code}, function(data) {
  var commodity_desc = data[0];
  alert(commodity_desc);
});
```

Comment: ***clarification :*** why is it a risky move to add `dataType:'json'` we can see in his php he is returning an array being `json_encode` ?

Comment: ***justification:*** @guradio Personal experience. I don't have a valid explanation for it. Many a times, removing that line worked for me. `:)`

Comment: @Jana What you just commented makes no sense. Did you understand the question and my answer? Why did you comment this?

Comment: Thank you, this is great. But I do not understand how the json DataType is risky?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i see happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 0):

error in this line `data: "commodity_code: commodity_code",` .. you can simple pass the `commodity_code` variable..

```
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'get_code.php',
  method: "POST",                         
  data: commodity_code, 
  dataType: 'json',                      
  success:function(data) {
        var commodity_desc = data[0];
        alert(commodity_desc);
  }  
});
```